# How can I force tmux to sort my sessions alphabetically?

Tags: tmux

I thought that in tmux, the list of sessions (`<prefix>-s`) is always automatically sorted alphabetically. I seem to remember this being so always. I create my sessions with names specifically taylored to  this  assumption.

Lately, when I accidentally close a session and recreate it, it appears at the bottom of the list, which breaks muscle memory.

[image]

**How  can I configure tmux (version 3.1b) to  sort sessions alphabetically?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like tmux in versions ≤ 2.9a sorted sessions alphabetically,
but starting from 3.1b this behavior changed.

You can see what `<prefix>-s` is bound to using the `list-keys` command. At the time of writing the default is `choose-tree -Zs`.

From [tmux(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html):

> `choose-tree [-GNrswZ] [-F format] [-f filter] [-O sort-order] [-t target-pane] [template]`
>
>   Put a pane into tree mode, where a session, window or pane may be chosen
>   interactively from a list. [...]
>   **`-s`**
>   starts with sessions collapsed.
>   **`-Z`**
>   zooms the pane.
>   [...]
>   **`-O`**
>   specifies the initial sort field:
>   one of ‘index’, ‘name’, or ‘time’ (activity).

You can rebind the key to whatever you like. In your case,
adding the following line to `~/.tmux.conf` should be sufficient:

```
bind s choose-tree -Zs -O name
```

Comment: After over a decade of use, this was a major shock to me when they changed the behavior to this.  Argh.